# Missing 'onload.js' file breaks Chrome Extensions OAuth

Tags: oauth, google-chrome-extension

I am going through the process of updating a Google Chrome extension from Manifest v1 to Manifest v2.  I won't say that things have been going swimmingly, largely due to outdated documentation at Google's own [Chrome Extensions website](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/index.html).

Here is the latest:

Google's documentation for using OAuth from within an extension tells me to include the following three files in my manifest:

```
chrome_ex_oauth.html  
chrome_ex_oauth.js  
chrome_ex_oauthsimple.js
```

The first of these files, chrome_ex_oauth.html, is basically the redirect page that is opened when an extension first uses OAuth to get an initial request token.  In the updated version of this very spare webpage, the head section lists *three* javascript files to load: the two listed above, and one called:

```
onload.js
```

When chrome_ex_oauth.html is opened by my extension, I get no indication of errors beyond a failure to load the non-existent 'onload.js' file.  Clearly, I am missing something here.  The OAuth sequence never succeeds in completing, and indeed there is no indication that it is ever initiated.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

After posting this question, I compared the old and new versions of chrome_ex_oauth.html.  I saw that in the former, while there was no mention of the onload.js script, there was the following in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoad() {
        ChromeExOAuth.initCallbackPage();
    };
</script>
```

This function was called inline:

```
<body onload="onload();">
...
```

As of Manifest v2, it is my understanding that inline javascript is strictly prohibited, so this couldn't fly.  A call to load onload.js was added to the document head instead.  It looks as if a link to the actual file in Google's documentation was overlooked.  It's easy enough to write, but here is what I put in onload.js:

```
window.onload = function() { ChromeExOAuth.initCallbackPage(); };
```

After that, the redirect worked just fine and I was able to complete the OAuth process.

Let me know if it doesn't work for you.